# VBA to export data to CSV file (only values)

Tags: excel, vba, csv, export

I would like to carry out the captioned task with the following codes modified from extendoffice.com (thank you).

```
Sub export_data_to_CSV()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim xFile As Variant
Dim xFileString As String
Dim LR As Long
LR = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("MAIN").Range("A1:A50001"))

Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Worksheets("MAIN").Range("A2:J" & LR)


Application.ActiveSheet.Copy
Application.ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
WorkRng.Copy Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
Set xFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
xFileString = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", filefilter:="Comma Separated Text (*.CSV), *.CSV")
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xFileString, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

The code works fine, however, it saves all formulas and even my button to the target file.  What should I do to the code if I only want to save values to the target CSV file?

Comment: CSV's can't have formulas or buttons, how does your csv file have them?

Comment: oops.  This code ends with the target file left opened.  After I close and re-open it, the file become a REAL CSV file without any formulas and buttons.

If I want to close the target file instantly with the code, what lines should I add?

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False`? Though I would not work with `ActiveWorkbook` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV files can't have formulas or buttons by definition. I think you're just seeing them in the currently open Excel instance, but if you were to open the newly saved CSV file, they would not be present.

To address your follow-up question:

> If I want to close the target file instantly with the code, what lines should I add?

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some demo code.  It:

1. copies *Sheet1* to a new workbook
2. clears all formula cells in the clone (*copied*) worksheet
3. saves the clone as *.csv*
4. closes the clone workbook

```
Sub KopyKat()
'
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select 'move to sheet
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy   'copy sheet to new workbook

    ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(-4123).Clear 'get rid of formulas

    'then save as .csv

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\garys\Desktop\bk.csv", FileFormat _
        :=xlCSVUTF8, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close 'close the new workbook

    ' the original workbook is now active again
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for your answer.  The 4th line gave me Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed.

Comment: @JohnLiu  Note the posted code is saving to a file on **my** directory....you must modify.